# How can I achieve this via oops concepts

Tags: oop

I am facing a design problem. This must only be solved by applying oops concepts. I am describing the problem below.

Problem: Suppose You have a class called X . It has two Paid (Chargeable) methods like m, n. Their may be many consumers classes of these methods. Someone **pays for m**, someone **pays for n** and someone **pays for both m, n**.

Now I have to design my X class in such a way that consumers **can only see that method for which they make payment.** How can we do this via OOPS concepts? **I can make appropriate changes in my X class to achieve this design**. Sample class is written below.

```
class X { // service class

    public m(){ // do some stuff
    }

    public n(){ // do some stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create 3 interfaces: one containing the `m` method, one containing `n` and a third containing both (the third interface can extend the two others). Then make your class `X` implement those interfaces.

You will then be able to expose the appropriate interface to your consumers, depending on their needs, while still using the same `X` class.

```
interface M { // exposed to customers paying for m
    void m();
}

interface N { // exposed to customers paying for n
    void n();
}

interface Mn extends M, N {} // exposed to customers paying for both

class X implements Mn {

    @Override
    public m(){ // do some stuff
    }

    @Override
    public n(){ // do some stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: can you give me sample code for solving this design.

Comment: Any consumer can call both method of X class simply by creating its object. How this solve purpose.
Where you check or restrict consumer to pay first and then do access.

Comment: Don't let your consumers see the X class. They should have methods accepting the appropriate interface. You can then call those method with an instance of X, without them being able to see the method they shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

You'd better use polymorphism concept

As example, based on assumption that m and n has different types:

```
class X{  // service class

    public Pay(NType n){ // do some stuff
        }
    public Pay(MType m){ // do some stuff
        }
    public Pay(NType n, MType m){ // do some stuff
            Pay(n);
            Pay(m); 
        }
}
```

Comment: You are using overloading in your example, and both the signature and the method name are the same. The variable name doesn't make a distinction.

Comment: How can you restrict the visibility of these methods in any consumer class.

Comment: If they are public you cannot.

Comment: My example based on the assumption that m and n - have different types. I've added clarification about it.

Comment: You are allow to change the public method to any (private ,protected,default) for achieving this design.

Comment: You can use any access modifiers for these methods. I've used in the example just same (publicly) like in your example above. You can use any combination of access modifiers for all of these methods depends on your needs

Comment: But dear, your example not related to my question , it does not solve the purpose of question.

Comment: Why not? TypeN and TypeM are supposed to be appropriate type of payment, so you cannot call inappropriate method because you'll use appropriate classes for that in each case (as example - CashPaymentType and CardPaymentType). You could also limit access to these classes by using of protected access modifier or others depends on your code structure.

Comment: So if, as example, protected class CashPayment inherited from protected internal CashPaymentType in separate assembly, then all of its descendants in other assemblies will be able use only CashPaymentType, not CardPaymentType. Thus it will be impossible to call wrong code.

Comment: Also, you can use additional TypeNM to limit access for pay (n, m) method.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not taking advantage of the class state. Class can store information in its instance fields about the user, and change its behavior accordingly.

One possible option would be:

```
class Payment {

    int paymentType = 0; // fill with constructor for i.e.

    public pay(int sum){
        // some common behavior
        switch(this.paymentType){
           case 1:
              // pay 1 logic
              break;
           case 2:
              // pay 2 logic
              break;  
        }
        // some other common behavior
    }
}
```

In another design you might use the Strategy pattern to have family of decoupled algorithms.

In the above code I assumed we are talking about some logically related code. If the code has nothing in common, you might even split it into other classes.

---

Update: I wouldn't advice on using it, but you can implement the Template Method pattern. The problem is you are going to overuse inheritance.

```
abstract class Payment {

    public Pay(int sum){
       // some common code
       this.doPay(sum);
    }

    abstract protected doPay(int sum);
}

class PaymentOne : Payment {

    protected doPay(int sum){
        // pay 1 logic
    }
}

class PaymentTwo : Payment {

    protected doPay(int sum){
        // pay 2 logic
    }
}
```

Comment: please understand the problem statement.
Problem is that , I have to restricts the consumer to any methods of my class if they don't make payments .
If methods are easily visible to consumers , they can call it by their choice.

Comment: Why not encapsulate this logic into the class and act upon?

Comment: I appreciate you effort , but if any consumer extends the parent abstarct class , they can call any of these two methods.
we have to design our class in such a way that consumer must do payment to both method to access both method and can pay for single method to access specific single method.

Comment: Are you talking about a developer which would extend the second example of my answer? If he extends the base abstract class, he cannot have access to the derived classes' methods. Only to the common code.

Comment: Got it !! you are getting confused with  method name payment.
Actually they are (m,n) paid method not free.

Comment: No Sir. 
Problem is that Consumers can call those methods in which they grant access.

Comment: It's a little bit hard to understand what you are looking for. If you make your method public, everyone can access it. How do you plan to "hide" it for specific clients? Based on what? I showed you some ways which make more sense. In each, the client is able to perform only what has been defined. In the first example that method has different behaviors based on the client state. In the second example you can create several classes which each expose different logic to be used. Consider those solution, or clarify better your purpose.

Comment: What you last edited is the exact problem statement.
we have to redesign our class X. method can be public private protected